# Image gallery with remote json for Android

Tags: android, json, android-gallery, appcelerator-mobile

I wonder if there are any tutorials, examples etc on how to build an image gallery for Android with appcelerator?

I want to display my photos from my FB page. I have the json and are logged in with auth token ready.

Any ideas or links would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the android tutorial from the source:   http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Here is an example gist from the appcelerator dev forum
https://gist.github.com/1163654

Comment: Ok i couldn´t fit this here so pls look at this and see if you could help me out. (http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/138254/no-images-in-gallery-android)

Comment: turn on logging and check the logs to make sure you really connected to facebook and you are looking at public or accessible photos.  You can use the facebook api explorer to make sure you graph calls are coorect

Answer (score 0):

turn on logging and check the logs to make sure you really connected to facebook and you are looking at public or accessible photos.  You can use the facebook api explorer to make sure you graph calls are correct.  You must also make sure you setup your facebook app to get all the permissions needed for facebook.  And your internet permissions for android app.  If you haven't done Android or Java, this is a bit complex.   [link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)